# WCF exception when reading from msmq queue

Tags: wcf, iis, msmq, silverlight-5.0, was

I have the following problem:

I have a silveright 5 project and wcf (iis/was hosted) project (.net 4).

The wcf project contains multiple services that are basicHttpBinding binded and one service that is netMsmqBinding binded.

There's one use case for this app where a user can generate some excel exports up to 30 files per user and up to 10 users.
This is a long running operation, up to 3 minutes per file.

At first the export service was httpBinded and with a request to generate more than 15 reports it would fail.
So I've increased the timeouts. This clearly was not the right solution for the problem.

So I've decided to use a queue and I've changed the binding for export services from basicHttpBinding to netMsmqBinding.

The workflow is the following:

The silverlight client would make a request for every file to the following method in ReportsService:

```
[SecurityTokenValidation]
    [ErrorLogging]
    public string GenerateTablesReport(List<MeasurementDescription> measurements)
    {
        if (measurements == null || measurements.Count.Equals(0))
        {
            throw new FaultException("Invalid argument.", new FaultCode(ErrorCodes.InvalidArgumentException));
        }

        //put on queue from here

        ExportsServiceClient exportsServiceClient = new ExportsServiceClient();

        exportsServiceClient.GenerateTablesReport(measurements.ToArray());

        return new Guid().ToString();
    }
```

In the above method I'm sending with putting the message further on queue.
I created a private transactional queue named ExportsService with the required security rights.

So far this works. I can see the messages on the queue.

**The problem is the ExportsService fails when trying to read the messages and all of them end up in a "retry" folder.**

I tried everything in the last two days. 
I tried with some simple toy projects just to check if msmq stuff is working on the machine.

**In svclog I found this exception.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqBindingMonitor.OnTimer(Object state)System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005): Remote computer is not available.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(String machineName)**

The ExportsService look like this:

```
public class ExportsService : IExportsService
{
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
    [SecurityTokenValidation]
    [ErrorLogging]
    public void GenerateTablesReport(List<MeasurementDescription> measurements)
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            if (measurements == null || measurements.Count.Equals(0))
            {
                throw new FaultException("Invalid argument.", new FaultCode(ErrorCodes.InvalidArgumentException));
            }

            BusinessFactory.ReportsManager.GenerateTablesReport(measurements);

            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

The intersting bits in web config look like this:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/ExportsService"
    binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetMsmqBinding_IExportsService"
    contract="WCF.ExportsService.IExportsService" name="NetMsmqBinding_IExportsService" />
</client>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>

    <behavior name="BatchingBehavior">
      <transactedBatching maxBatchSize="16"/>
    </behavior>

  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="foobar">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="60"  maxConcurrentInstances="60"   maxConcurrentSessions="60" />
    </behavior>

    <behavior name="ThrottlingBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="4"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>

  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="defaultBasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <netMsmqBinding>
    <binding name="defaultNetMsmqBinding">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="NetMsmqBinding_IExportsService">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netMsmqBinding>

</bindings>

<services>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="ThrottlingBehavior" name="FLM.Web.Services.ExportsService">
    <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/ExportsService" binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultNetMsmqBinding" behaviorConfiguration="BatchingBehavior" contract="FLM.Web.Services.IExportsService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="foobar" name="FLM.Web.Services.ReportsService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpBinding"  contract="FLM.Web.Services.IReportsService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="foobar" name="FLM.Web.Services.SecurityService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpBinding" contract="FLM.Web.Services.ISecurityService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="foobar" name="FLM.Web.Services.OrderingService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpBinding"  contract="FLM.Web.Services.IOrderingService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="foobar" name="FLM.Web.Services.ReportConfigurationService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpBinding"  contract="FLM.Web.Services.IReportConfigurationService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="foobar" name="FLM.Web.Services.AdminService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpBinding"  contract="FLM.Web.Services.IAdminService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

</services>
```